# Unable to rebind the data in JQX Grid : [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: angularjs

I have already passed in researching about 4-5 days in order to identify the issue that why I am not able to rebind the data.

Below is the scenario :

1. I am using the jqx grid as mentioned in following link that's
   displaying data from the sql database using angular js with all CRUD
   operations.

   http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/saveloadstate.html
2. On page load - grid is displaying data which is expected.
3. on the same page there is "Refresh" button thats rebind the data again from the database where I have specified same load function that binds the data with grid on first time page load.

**Issue:** When I click on Refresh - I am getting following error message :

**[$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!**

Would you please help me out to resolve this issue - whether its angular behavior which cant be possible to implement or I am doing anything wrong ?

your help will be highly appreciated !

**Note :** I have asked about the same on following forum topic as well and waiting for the reply.

http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/refresh-grid-data-from-server-after-deleting-row/#post-69834

Thanks and Regards,
Dipti

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to help you, if you do not post a complete minimal example.

In general, if you want to refresh a grid bound to a a remote data source, you can do the following:

```
$scope.gridInstance.source.dataBind()
```

where `gridInstance` is the name you assigned to the `jqx-instance` HTML attribute:

```
<jqx-grid jqx-instance="gridInstance" 
          jqx-create="gridSettings" 
          jqx-settings="gridSettings"></jqx-grid>
```

I hope this helps; otherwise, post a complete minimal example; then we can help you also with a complete answer!
 - badera